# Appcelerator hierarchical selector for TSS

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy, tss

How can we set style using hierarchical selector in TSS?
For example in index.xml file I have

```
<TableView id="myTable">
      <TableViewRow>
          <Label text="Row"></Label>
      </TableViewRow>
</TableView>
```

For this I want to set Set style to `Label` inside `#myTable`
Like in CSS we can do it

```
#myTable Label{ 
  //style
}
```

But this is not working in TSS.

So does anyone know how can we set style using an hierarchical selector?

Answer (score 2):

TSS isn't CSS, though both are designed to allow setting visual properties. I am almost positive there is no way to hierarchically set a TSS rule. You must apply to the object directly or to the object as a class. So, you could create a class called 'tablelabel' and set it's properties, then apply the class to the label object in the table... But it's a direct assignment not a hierarchical one.

Comment: Correct, Alloy's TSS does not support hierarchical selectors. See http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Styles_and_Themes for all information on TSS.